# Change Font in UISearchBar in Swift 4

Tags: ios11, swift4

I'm hating Apple's for all the changes from Swift 3.1 to Swift 4. Now I have another dilemma. I was able to customize my search bar but now I need to change the source of the input text and the placeholder.

[image]

I already moved heaven and earth but I can not find the solution to change the font. I also want to change the search icon to a custom one.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4:**

Change font:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [CustomSearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 21.0)]
```

Change color:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [CustomSearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue:UIColor.red]
```

Search icon:

```
searchController.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "search_icon"), for: UISearchBarIcon.search, state: .normal)
```

Placeholder:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [CustomSearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this in **Swift 5**:

```
searchBar[keyPath: \.searchTextField].font = UIFont(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Latest swift:

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.regular(15), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = attributes
```